# How to include jars in different drives in to the manifest file in a jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath, manifest

I am working on a legacy application where it uses Javadoc generation using ant task by using the package `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs`. There I need to pass the classpath given by the maven. this classpath mostly has jar paths in the maven local repository.

```
        Javadoc javadoc = new Javadoc();
        javadoc.setUseExternalFile(true);
        javadoc.setProject(proj);
        javadoc.setClasspath(new Path(proj, classpath));
```

The problem is this classpath is long enough so that execution on Windows is not permitted which cause the following error.

```
enterJavadoc failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javadoc.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long code here
```

For this problem what I did was to create a pathing jar which includes the long classpath in its manifest file. So I add this jar file as the classpath for Javadoc task. I used ManifestClassPath task in the ant to generate relative paths for the jars in my long classpath.

```
    ManifestClassPath mc = new ManifestClassPath();
    mc.setProject(proj);
    mc.addClassPath(new Path(proj, classPath));
    mc.setJarFile(new File(pathingJar));
    mc.setProperty("classpath");
    mc.setMaxParentLevels(20);
    mc.execute();
    Jar jar = new Jar();
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    Manifest.Attribute attribute = new Manifest.Attribute();
    attribute.setName("Class-Path");
    attribute.setValue(proj.getProperty("classpath"));
    manifest.addConfiguredAttribute(attribute);
    jar.addConfiguredManifest(manifest);
    jar.setDestFile(new File(pathingJar));
    jar.setProject(proj);
    jar.execute();
    javadoc.setClasspath(new Path(proj, pathingJar));
```

This solution works until I develop this in the same drive where the maven local repository is located. But maven local repository is located in a different drive it fails as it can't generate a relative path for a different drive. Then I tried with processing classpath by using the file protocol like following

```
Class-Path: file:///C:/mvn_repo/...  file:///C:/mvn_repo/... ...
```

This solution did not seem to be working as the Javadoc task is failing. Is there any other approach to try using a pathing jar to fix this long classpath issue?

Comment: Could you share us the error log? is this the package org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc ?

Comment: @JRichardsz please see my updated question. I am using org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs package

Comment: You can't. Class-path entries in the Manifest are *relative* URLs, which are interpreted relative to the location of the containing JAR file. You can't put an absolute path in there of any description.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne is there any other way than using jar file. I cannot edit CLASSPATH environment variable or use wildcards since classpath includes jar from maven local repo so that I need to use jars with the exact version

Comment: Did you try using link ? On the drive of the pathing jar, you can create a folder link to maven directory. `mklink /J "mvn_repo_link" "C:\mvn_repo"`. And then you can use relative path through `mvn_repo_link` directory.

Comment: I suggest you edit your title and question to reflect your actual problem, which is with the Javadoc command line. The JAR Manifest Class-path issue is just a rabbit-hole.

Comment: @Genu Your solution works for me. Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, yes my actual problem is related to Javadoc with the command line. But I actually stuck with this Manifest Class-Path problem which is a solution to my actual problem. So I created this question to find an answer for Manifest Class-Path issue and also if the pathing jar approach is not working I hoped to find a different approach.

Comment: It's not a solution to your current problem, because it doesn't work. You need to focus on the problem, not the non-solution. The fact that you are now asking for a different approach proves it.

Comment: @GayanViranka Done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @MarquisofLorne, you can't.

> *Class-path entries in the Manifest are relative URLs*

Anyway, you can use a **workaround** with a folder link. On the drive of your *pathing jar*, you can create a folder link to the maven directory. Folder links can point to another drive.

```
mklink /J "mvn_repo_link" "C:\mvn_repo".
```

And then you can use relative path through `mvn_repo_link` subdirectory